# Avoiding the reset of JS text inputs

Tags: javascript, html, input, onclick, innerhtml

A bit of an anomaly is showing up in my code.
I'm working on a graphing calculator, where it may be necessary for users to enter multiple expressions for evaluation. To do this I have a text input & a button that essentially adds a new input to the parent div each time it is clicked, like this:

```
document.getElementById("add").onclick =  function(){
  document.getElementById("boxes").innerHTML += '<br/><input type="text" spellcheck="false" id="b' + nBox +'" class="eq"/>';
}
```

Whilst this works, the values of previous inputs in the div are being reset each time I press this button. I'm assuming adding to the `innerHTML` has some sort of clearance effect on other elements in the parent div.

Is there a way I can prevent this?

Comment: Yes, `innerHTML` is bad and you should use something else

Comment: You mustn’t set innerhtml. You are right that it resets state. 
You need to use appendChild. Look it up!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Altering the innerHTML causes the browser to re-render the entire page and wipes the state in those inputs. appendChild should clean that up:

```
<button id="add">Add</button>
<div id="boxes"></div>

<script>
document.getElementById("add").onclick =  function(){
  let input = document.createElement('input');
  input.type = "text";
  input.spellcheck="false";
  input.classList = ["eq"];
  document.getElementById("boxes").appendChild(input);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use innerHTML for these things, have a look at [Element.appendChild()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild).
In your case, try:

```
document.getElementById("boxes").appendChild('<br/><input type="text" spellcheck="false" id="b' + nBox +'" class="eq"/>');
```

Please also have a look at .createElement() for cleaner code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - however in this case appendChild wont work like that - as it takes HTML DOM objects as input. That being said, yes I will use DOM element creation.

Comment: You are right, i didn't considered that. Thanks for correction!
One could still use new DOMParser().parseFromString(htmlStr, "text/html"); but as i said, createElement have more advantages.